# How to shorten image sequence output in tree command?

Tags: shell, tree

I'm in a directory where running `tree` command produces something like this:

```
├── directory1
│   └── image_sequence
│       ├── image.0001.jpg
│       ├── image.0002.jpg
│       ├── image.0003.jpg
│       ├── image.0004.jpg
│       ├── image.0005.jpg
│       └── image.0006.jpg
│ 
└── directory2
    ├── somefile.ext
    └── someanotherfile.ext2
```

The image sequence inside `image_sequence` produces a large listing that I want to trim. My desired output is something like below:

```
├── directory1
│   └── image_sequence
│       └── image.####.jpg
│ 
└── directory2
    ├── somefile.ext
    └── someanotherfile.ext2
```

Can the output of `tree` command somehow be modified?

Comment: I'm confused about whether you want to use the `tree` command or not.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/334438/117549 may be the answer to this question; see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368884/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47805/117549

Comment: Tree command can be used, except that the whole sequence listing needs to converted to `image.####.jpg` format. Then use Python to modify image sequence output. The links you gave suggested the flags which will completely omit the output of image sequence. There's also an option called `--filelimit` which is close to what I want, but again it completely omits the image sequence output. I fear that using Python completely will not produce the identical output (the symbols and all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tree | sed '/\xe2\x94\x9c\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 image\.[0-9]\+\.jpg/d; s/\(\xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 image\.\)[0-9]\+\(\.jpg\)/\1####\2/'
```

- The first `/.../d;` deletes all lines containing `├── image.[0-9]+.jpg` (pseudo-pattern) entries
- The second `s/.../\1####\2/` replaces the last line `└── image.[0-9]+.jpg`

Output:

```
$ tree | sed  '/\xe2\x94\x9c\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 image\.[0-9]\+\.jpg/d; s/\(\xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80\xe2\x94\x80 ima
ge\.\)[0-9]\+\(\.jpg\)/\1####\2/'
.
├── directory1
│   └── image_sequence
│       └── image.####.jpg
└── directory2
    ├── someanotherfile.ext
    └── somefile.ext

3 directories, 8 files
```

This will of course only work if all files in `image_sequence` match the image pattern and will modify filenames in other directories matching the patterns. If the last file in `image_sequence` for example is `readme.txt`, then you will remove all image entries instead.

Comment: What are those hex values?

Comment: `├──` and `└──`. This is why it only works if all files match those patterns. So I wouldn't use this solution if you have other files inside `image_sequence` or other  `image.xxxx.jpg` files in other directories.

Comment: One last doubt. I want to replace `├──` and `└──` to something simpler. Say `|-` and `L`. Because my shell is not printing it well. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, I see there's an option for `--charset` which take _ascii_ or _unicode_. Can you please modify your answer with that?

Comment: With the ascii option it's `tree --charset=ascii | sed  '/|-- image\.[0-9]\+\.jpg/d; s/\(\`-- image\.\)[0-9]\+\(\.jpg\)/\1####\2/'`

Comment: Nope! That prints out all the images. Not even `####`ing.

Comment: Works for me using `tree v1.7.0`. With ascii I get prefixes `|--` and `\`--` which are matched by the above `sed`. If it doesn't match it will of course change nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the numerical parts of the sequential filenames with `#`s, using a `sed` expression (similar to the second one in [Freddy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521522/90751)).  `uniq` can then remove the duplicate lines:

```
tree | sed 's/\.[0-9]\+\.jpg/.####.jpg/g' | uniq
```

This will still leave two entries for the images (because the final line uses a different symbol in the tree-drawing part), but it has still trimmed the list down to a manageable length:

```
.
|-- directory1
|   `-- image_sequence
|       |-- image.####.jpg
|       `-- image.####.jpg
`-- directory2
    |-- someanotherfile.ext2
    `-- somefile.ext
```

Comment: `bash: s/\.[0-9]\+\.jpg/.####.jpg/g: No such file or directory`

Comment: It's important to quote the `s/.../.../g` part with single quotes (`'`), or else bash will try to expand the `[0-9]` part (and fail).

Comment: I just copy pasted your snippet.

Comment: @SantoshKumar I accidentally chopped the word `sed` out while editing.  Could you try again?